# Transformer Phasor Diagram And Circuit Diagram

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism, electromagnetic, phasor

I have been reading the construction of a practical transformer and facing difficulty in understanding the phasor diagram of it.
When we connect \$V_1\$ supply to the primary side, say \$V_1 = sin(wt)\$ a current starts to flow flux is induced in the core, with the same phase angle as that of the applied voltage, this induces emf ( i.e., \$e_1 = sin(wt-\pi/2)\$ ) now emf in secondary coil will also be induced, \$e_2=-sin(wt-\pi/2)\$.
So, from here we can infer that \$e_1\$ and \$e_2\$ are lagging and leading respectively (taking flux as reference) by \$\pi/2\$. But when we draw the phasor diagram we show them just lagging.

Why is it happening, or I'm just missing something?

Fig1: Phasor Diagram

[image: Phasor Diagram]

Fig2: Circuit Diagram

[image: Circuit Diagram]